# how can I configure vim + ctags to recognize rails ActiveRecord scope definitions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, vim, ctags

say that I have this code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :recent, where(:created_at => 2.weeks.ago)
end
```

...  And then in vim, I go to another file and see:

```
User.recent
```

Is there a way I can configure ctags so that when looking up :tag recent, it will take me to the scope declaration?  It appears that it only looks for things that are actual method definitions.

...

Also, Is there a way to specify a path for tags?  What I am getting at is, I would like to generate ctags for all the gems in a given rails project so that I can jump to 3rd party code method declarations from within my code.  Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try something like VimRuby : https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/wiki/VimRubySupport ?

Answer (score 8):

To create a custom tag for ActiveRecord scopes just use the `—regex-<LANG>` command line option. The option requires a regex replacement pattern containing (1) the pattern matching the language feature in our source code, and (2) the tag entry that should be created for it. In our case, we want to look for the scope definition, and we want to create a tag with the name of the scope.

`--regex-ruby=/^[ \t]*scope[ \t]*:([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\1/`

Now, if we see an ActiveRecord scope in our text editor we can quickly jump to the definition in the model!

The option will be applied by default when added to the .ctags configuration file.

`echo '--regex-ruby=/^[ \t]*scope[ \t]*:([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\1/' >> .ctags`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `ctags` only indexes method and variable/constant definitions by default. Also Vim's default behaviour is to jump to the tag. If you often need to jump to the `scope` maybe you'll need a custom mapping.

As for the second part of your question, you could use this:

```
:set tags=/path/to/tags
```

or use the `-a` flag to append your new tags to a previously existing `tags` file.